# Can i get the particular disk space(like C: ) using Java program?

Tags: java

I used the SystemEnvironment class in Java for getting system information.

In that I can get only RAM size, I can't get the specific disk space like c: and D:

code is,

com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean mxbean = (com.sun.management.OperatingSystemMXBean)ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
System.out.println("Total RAM:"+mxbean.getTotalSwapSpaceSize()/(1024*1024*1024)+""+"GB");

Can i get this in information in a Java program?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [`java.io.File`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) API:

- `long getTotalSpace()`: Returns the size of the partition named by this abstract pathname.
- `long getUsableSpace()`: Returns the number of bytes available to this virtual machine on the partition named by this abstract pathname.
- `long getFreeSpace()`: Returns the number of unallocated bytes in the partition named by this abstract path name.

---

The following snippet shows an example on how to use it:

```
for (File root : File.listRoots()) {
    System.out.format("%s (%d bytes free)%n", root, root.getFreeSpace());
}
```